# How to make one background mild between two background in Homepage?

Tags: html, css

So I added Two background in Homepage. One is Blue shade and another is an Image. I want to That Blue shade to see more that image. How can I do it. 
HTML:

```
<div class="banner banner-4 banner-4-bg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="banner-content">
              <h1>The Easiest Way to Find Job</h1>
              <p>Find Jobs, Employment & Career Opportunities</p>
              <div class="banner-search">
                <form action="#" class="search-form">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Keywords">
                  <select class="selectpicker" id="search-location">
                    <option value="" selected>Location</option>
                    <option value="california">California</option>
                    <option value="las-vegas">Las Vegas</option>
                    <option value="new-work">New Work</option>
                    <option value="carolina">Carolina</option>
                    <option value="chicago">Chicago</option>
                    <option value="silicon-vally">Silicon Vally</option>
                    <option value="washington">Washington DC</option>
                    <option value="neveda">Neveda</option>
                  </select>
                  <button class="button primary-bg"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>Search Job</button>
                </form>
                <div class="trending-key">
                  <span>Trending Keywords:</span>
                  <a href="#">designer</a>
                  <a href="#">php</a>
                  <a href="#">ios</a>
                  <a href="#">Android</a>
                  <a href="#">Accounting</a>
                  <a href="#">Management</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

MY CSS:

```
.banner-4-bg {
  background: url(../images/bg/banner_home.png) , url(../images/bg/banner-4-bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner-4 .banner-content {
  padding: 290px 0 210px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

What I have now :
[image]

And What I want:

[image]

Help me out Good people :)

Comment: Share the html code.

Comment: Just Edited. Please Can you check

Comment: can you fix the images? it is not visible due to path!

Comment: How can I do it? let me know

Comment: try this: which ever image you want it to be first that should be the first in the list `url`. : background:url(../images/bg/banner-4-bg.jpg, url(../images/bg/banner_home.png)) no-repeat center;

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it:

1. Modify the image and make the same as displayed in the second one.
2. Make another `div` same width and height as image and `{position: absolute}` such that it overlaps the image then `{ background-color: 'some gray or black color', opacity: 0.5 }` **(adjust opacity and background-color accordingly)**. also, write all the displaying content on the banner in this **div**.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the transparency of an image by using CSS `opacity`, where `opacity` is between 0.0 - 1.0 and the lower value, the more transparent, e.g.:

```
.banner-4-bg {
  background: url(../images/bg/banner_home.png) , url(../images/bg/banner-4-bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.banner-4 .banner-content {
  padding: 290px 0 210px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go(view it in full screen mode):

> I tried to get the images you shared and used it may the clarity is not clear. You may need to use the texts field as you want. As I mentioned in comments interchange the `background:urls` that should fix for you.
>
> When using the multiple background images, images will be stacked upon each other and the first is the closest to the view.

```css
.banner-4-bg {
  background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/DyJRcGNB/Px3iz.png), url(https://i.postimg.cc/wTL0vQZ8/azHDz.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner-4 .banner-content {
  padding: 290px 0 210px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-4-bg">

</div>
<div class="banner banner-4 banner-4-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="banner-content">
          <h1>The Easiest Way to Find Job</h1>
          <p>Find Jobs, Employment & Career Opportunities</p>
          <div class="banner-search">
            <form action="#" class="search-form">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Keywords">
              <select class="selectpicker" id="search-location">
                <option value="" selected>Location</option>
                <option value="california">California</option>
                <option value="las-vegas">Las Vegas</option>
                <option value="new-work">New Work</option>
                <option value="carolina">Carolina</option>
                <option value="chicago">Chicago</option>
                <option value="silicon-vally">Silicon Vally</option>
                <option value="washington">Washington DC</option>
                <option value="neveda">Neveda</option>
              </select>
              <button class="button primary-bg"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>Search Job</button>
            </form>
            <div class="trending-key">
              <span>Trending Keywords:</span>
              <a href="#">designer</a>
              <a href="#">php</a>
              <a href="#">ios</a>
              <a href="#">Android</a>
              <a href="#">Accounting</a>
              <a href="#">Management</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ap Anik did the answer was helpful?